# How to add new items to popup menu after click

Tags: android, onclick, menuitem, android-menu, popupmenu

I have a button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bot_button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="@string/bot_button1_tx" />
```

This is my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = this;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot_button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    Log.d(className, "onCreate");  

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bot_button1:
            showPopupMenu(v, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
};  

private void showPopupMenu(final View v, Integer i){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, popupMenu.getMenu());
        break;
    }

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).
                setTitle("TITLE").
                setMessage("MESSAGE").
                setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO: user specific action
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
              }).create().show();
        return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

How can I display more items when an item from the PopupMenu is selected (clicked)? Ideal case scenario: PopupMenu remains visible after selection, and a new PopupMenu appears right next to the selected item. OR Popup Menu expands to show the subitems.

I tried to introduce a second PopupMenu onMenuItemClick(), but it only replaces the first PopupMenu.

Comment: In an app that I am creating I beleive that I created a completely custom menuing system using PopupWindow controls instead of PopupMenu controls. Of course I did this as I wanted a completely custom look and feel and mine however only needed single level. Looking around, I havent seen any information stating it is or isnt possible to have multiple PopupWindow controls on screen at once.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a new popup menu to solve this issue

```
public OnMenuItemClickListener listener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu2_3_3:  
            popupMenu2.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2_3_3, popupMenu2.getMenu());
            popupMenu2.show();
            popupMenu2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener2);
```